# No Multipart Configuration for Spring boot version 2.3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating an application and want to send user data along with his profile picture. I am using reactjs for frontend and java 1.8 with spring boot 2.3.1. I researched for 3 days and everywhere I see that we can send the user data and profile picture file as multipart form data from UI and then do the following in my controller to get the two different data.

`public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@RequestParam("user") String stringUserRequest, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)`

Here the user data is actually a JSON but is converted to a string and sent from UI.

But this keeps throwing the below error

`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`

I have searched a lot and it has something to do with the servelet version being higher than 3.0. There are a lot of questions regarding the same but all of them are for spring framework and not for spring boot in particular and have tried them also but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone tell me either how to create this Multipart Config for spring boot or how to degrade the servelet version?

Comment: Have you configured a multipart resolver?

Comment: No that is what I am looking for how to configure that I don't seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a multipart resolver in your configuration class, first you add these dependencies in your POM:

```
<!-- multipart resolver-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and you need to declare this Bean configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Finally, don't forget to specify the content type as `multipart/form-data` when sending your request.

EDIT:
the header Content-type should be multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------362947062764690924037801

Comment: This worked but is throwing a new exception that no multipart boundary can be found.